# How to fix a face that is breaking because of the verts

Tags: mesh, objects, faces

I am trying to create this form. The images explain my problem exactly. How do I fix the break of the faces?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to apply an edge split modifier?

Comment: it's a great looking form you're working on!
Perhaps to make it more clear for us you could post a picture with the wireframe on top of the mesh. If you don't know how to do that you can go to the Properties panel > Object > Display and check Wire and Draw All edges. Because I think there could be something wrong with the topology. Cheers!

Comment: Frank, a couple of helpful hints, here. First, in the screenshots, it might be helpful to include more of the screen, particularly the tool shelf (activated by the "T" key), and also upload a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit a link to the uploaded file into your question.

Comment: This is most likely caused by an ngon. Ngons are faces with more than four sides, and cause a multitude of problems, one of which is this. Cleanup your topology and make a quads based mesh

Comment: This is around an ngon problem but I think the shape it self can support it here. So there is something else too. Could you upload the file as indicated by @brasshat?